# dask read_csv timeout on Amazon s3 with big files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dask, dask-distributed

dask read_csv timeout on s3 for big files

```
s3fs.S3FileSystem.read_timeout = 5184000  # one day
s3fs.S3FileSystem.connect_timeout = 5184000  # one day

client = Client('a_remote_scheduler_ip_here:8786')

df = dd.read_csv('s3://dask-data/nyc-taxi/2015/*.csv')
len(df)
```

`len(df)` has timeout exception, if the file is small, then it just works well.

I think we need a way to set `s3fs.S3FileSystem.read_timeout` on the remote workers, not the local code, but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is a part of the stack trace:

> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/bytes/utils.py", line 238, in read_block
>     File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1333, in read
>     File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1303, in _fetch
>     File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1520, in _fetch_range
>     File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/response.py", line 81, in read
>   botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "None"

Comment: Side-note: s3fs is a virtual file system on top of Amazon S3. It is recommend that systems interact directly with S3 rather than using s3fs.

Comment: dask uses s3fs behind the scene, I think.

Comment: (s3fs does interact directly with S3, which is a REST API over HTTP)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the timeouts using the class attribute seems like a reasonable thing to do, but you are using a client talking with workers in other processes/machines. Therefore, you would need to set the attribute on the copies of the class on each worker for your method to take affect.

Better, perhaps, would be to set the blocksize being used by `read_csv` (64MB by default) to a smaller number. I assume that you are on a slower network, and this is why you are getting timeouts. If you need numbers below 5MB, the default readahead size in s3fs, then you should also pass `default_block_size` amongst the `storage_options` passed to `read_csv`

Note, finally, that both s3fs and dask allow for retries, on connection errors or general task errors. That may be enough to help you in the case that you only get this for the occasional laggy ready.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will set default_block_size and try again.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you did and what the outcome was.