# Is there a way to increase the read timeout in pyarrow. Getting AioReadTimeoutError

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Im trying to work with parquet files in an s3 bucket with pyarrow and I keep running into this error:

`OSError: IOError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://s3-bucket/s3-path/LOAD0000000B.parquet". Detail: Python exception: AioReadTimeoutError`

Does anyone know a way to increase the timeout in pyarrow?

Comment: Can you show more code? It sounds like you're using s3fs, in which case you can adjust the timeout in s3fs (Arrow is not doing the S3 reading in that case). e.g. see this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301693/s3fs-timeout-on-big-s3-files

Comment: Just came across the same issue